# How can I delete excess elements after using the after pseudo class selector?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to recreate a table and make it mobile responsive. Attached is what I am aiming for.[image]

This is What I have been able to achieve
[image]

However, I made use of the after pseudo selector to input the horizontal lines and my mockup only has the first five tables appearing. I set the display of the other elements to none but the horizontal rule comes on for everything.

[image]

Would there be anyway to disable this. I need the first five elements and no horizontal rule on the last element.

```css
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .date-container {
    width: 260px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
  }
  .calendar-container {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 85%;
    top: 2px;
    transform: translateX(3px);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  }
  .calendar-container img {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
  }
  .calendar-container>div span {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }
  .date-container div:last-of-type img {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    transform: translate(230px, 11px);
  }
  .text-container {
    margin: 0 10px 0 15px;
  }
  .text-container h1 {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .text-container h1>span {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    padding-right: 3px;
  }
  .email-table {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .email-table table {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
  }
  td,
  th {
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  .email-table table tr:nth-of-type(1) {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #EEEDED;
  }
  th:first-of-type>span img {
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    transform: translate(38px, -13px);
  }
  th:first-of-type {
    color: black;
  }
  th {
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
  }
  .date {
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  .date>span img {
    display: none;
  }
  th:first-of-type:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #838383;
    width: 2px;
    height: 15px;
    transform: translate(56px, -25px);
  }
  th:nth-of-type(2):after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #838383;
    width: 2px;
    height: 15px;
    transform: translate(15px, 3px);
  }
  th:nth-of-type(3)::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #838383;
    width: 1.5px;
    height: 15px;
    transform: translate(8px, 3px);
  }
  .email-table table tr:not(:nth-of-type(1)) {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    height: 95px;
  }
  .email-table table tr:not(:nth-of-type(1)):after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: black;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
  .email-table table tr:not(:nth-of-type(1)) td:first-of-type {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 1;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  .email-table table tr:not(:nth-of-type(1)):before {
    content: url('../assets/icon_mail_sp.svg');
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(15px, 10px);
  }
  .email-table table tr td:last-of-type {
    transform: translateX(120px);
  }
  .email-table table tr:not(:nth-of-type(4)) td:last-of-type::after {
    content: url('../assets/icon_arrow02.svg');
    width: 3px;
    height: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(3px);
  }
  .email-table table tr:nth-of-type(4) td:last-of-type span:last-of-type::after {
    content: url('../assets/icon_arrow02.svg');
    width: 3px;
    height: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(3px);
  }
  .second-data {
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 3;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: -1;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }
  .third-data {
    grid-row-start: 3;
    grid-row-end: 4;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: -1;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
  }
  td:last-of-type {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  .first-second-data {
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  .first-third-data {
    transform: translate(-20px, -27px);
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(2) td:first-of-type {
    transform: translate(20px, -2px);
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(2) td:nth-of-type(2) {
    transform: translate(20px, -15px);
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(2) td:nth-of-type(3) {
    transform: translate(5px, -15px);
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(3) td:first-of-type {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(3) td:first-of-type:after {
    visibility: visible;
    content: 'bbb.bbbb@example.com';
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-90px);
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(3) td:nth-of-type(2) {
    transform: translate(20px, -15px);
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(4) td:first-of-type {
    transform: translate(20px, -3px);
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(4) td:nth-of-type(2) {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(3) td:nth-of-type(2):after {
    visibility: visible;
    content: 'xxx@example.com, www.www@example.com';
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-108px, 92px);
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(5) td:first-of-type:after {
    visibility: visible;
    content: 'ddd.dddd@example.com';
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(-90px);
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(5) td:first-of-type {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .second-text span:first-of-type {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .second-text span:first-of-type:after {
    visibility: visible;
    content: 'vvv.vvv@example.com, uuu@example.com, ...';
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-150px, 15px);
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(6) td:first-of-type {
    transform: translate(20px);
  }
  .second-text span:last-of-type {
    transform: translate(40px, 15px);
    padding: 0 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
  .first-clip span:first-of-type img {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    transform: translateX(-5px);
  }
  .second-second-data {
    transform: translate( 27px, -20px);
  }
  .second-third-data {
    transform: translate(10px, -10px);
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .third-second-data {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  .third-third-data {
    transform: translate(10px, -20px);
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .fourth-second-data {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  .fourth-third-data {
    transform: translate(7px, 2px);
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .fourth-third-data {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .fourth-third-data:after {
    visibility: visible;
    content: '[ HR-888 ] Notice of official announcement';
    position: absolute;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transform: translate(-160px, -40px);
  }
  .last-attachment span:first-of-type {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .last-attachment span:first-of-type:after {
    visibility: visible;
    content: 'sss@example.com, rrr.rrrr@example.com, ...';
    position: absolute;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transform: translate(-140px, 5px);
  }
  .last-attachment span:last-of-type {
    transform: translate(50px, 2px);
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 0 3px;
  }
  .fifth-second-data {
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  .fifth-third-data {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .fifth-third-data:after {
    visibility: visible;
    content: '[HR-887(Revised: Office Expansion Project Tea...';
    position: absolute;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transform: translate(-120px, -15px);
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  tr td:last-of-type>span img {
    transform: translateX(60px);
    display: block;
  }
  .first-clip span:last-of-type>span img {
    transform: translateX(3px);
    display: block;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(7) td {
    display: none;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(8) td {
    display: none;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(9) td {
    display: none;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(10) td,
  tr:nth-of-type(10) td:last-of-type {
    display: none;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(11) td,
  tr:nth-of-type(11) td:last-of-type {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="email-table">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>From <span><img src="./assets/icon_arrow01.svg" alt=""></span></th>
      <th>To</th>
      <th>Subject</th>
      <th class="date">Date <span><img src="./assets/icon_arrow01.svg" alt=""></span></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>aaa@example.com</td>
      <td class="second-data first-second-data">zzz.zzz@example.com</td>
      <td class="third-data first-third-data">[ HR-888 ] Notice of official announcement</td>
      <td>0:20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bbb.bbbb@exam... </td>
      <td class="second-data second-second-data">yyy@example.com</td>
      <td class="third-data second-third-data">[web:333] "Web Contact"</td>
      <td>0:10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ccc@example.com </td>
      <td class="second-data third-second-data">
        <div class="text-attachment">
          <span>xxx@example.com, ...</span>
          <span>+1</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="third-data third-third-data">Happy New Year! Greetings for the New Year.</td>
      <td>
        <div class="attachment first-clip">
          <span><img src="./assets/icon_clip.svg" alt=""></span>
          <span>0:00</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ddd.dddd@exam...</td>
      <td class="second-data fourth-second-data">
        <div class="text-attachment second-text">
          <span>vvv.vvv@example.com, ... </span>
          <span>+1</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="third-data fourth-third-data">[HR-887(Revised: Office Expansion Project Team)] Notice of off... </td>
      <td>Jan 01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>eee@example.com</td>
      <td class="second-data fifth-second-data">
        <div class="text-attachment last-attachment">
          <span>sss@example.com, .... </span>
          <span>+2</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="third-data fifth-third-data">[Github] Logout page</td>
      <td>Jan 01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>fff.ffff@example.c... </td>
      <td>qqq.qqq@example.com</td>
      <td>［dev］ Postfix 3.1.12 / 3.2.9 / 3.3.4 / 3.4.5</td>
      <td>Jan 01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ggg@example.com </td>
      <td>ppp@example.com</td>
      <td>Re: [Github] Brush-up on loading animation </td>
      <td>Jan 01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>hhh.hhh@examp...</td>
      <td>ooo.ooo@example.com</td>
      <td>Workplace Summary for sample, Inc.: Jun 2 - Jun 9</td>
      <td>
        <div class="attachment">
          <span><img src="./assets/icon_clip.svg" alt=""></span>
          <span>Jan 01</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>iii@example.com</td>
      <td>nnn@example.com</td>
      <td>I love you</td>
      <td>
        <div class="attachment last-clip">
          <span><img src="./assets/icon_clip.svg" alt=""></span>
          <span>2019/12/31</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pablo-Diego-...</td>
      <td>Pablo-Diego-José-Francisc...
      </td>
      <td>[info:888] ABC EQUIPMENT COMPANY</td>
      <td>2019/12/31</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can target all the `tr` from the 6th element on with this rule:

```
tr:nth-of-type(6) ~ tr {
  display: none;
}
```

Because of your previous CSS rules using nesting, you have to use nesting as well to override the previous `display: grid` property like so:

```
.email-table table tr:nth-of-type(6) ~ tr {
  display: none;
}
```

Or with `!important`.

```
tr:nth-of-type(6) ~ tr {
  display: none !important;
}
```

As a general rule it is good to avoid nesting, and use class names for your elements. It will prevent this kind of problems.

```css
body {
  background: white;
  color: #323232;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica neue, roboto;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .date-container {
    width: 260px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
  }
  .calendar-container {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 85%;
    top: 2px;
    transform: translateX(3px);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  }
  .calendar-container img {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
  }
  .calendar-container>div span {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }
  .date-container div:last-of-type img {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    transform: translate(230px, 11px);
  }
  .text-container {
    margin: 0 10px 0 15px;
  }
  .text-container h1 {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .text-container h1>span {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    padding-right: 3px;
  }
  .email-table {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .email-table table {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
  }
  td,
  th {
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  .email-table table tr:nth-of-type(1) {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #EEEDED;
  }
  th:first-of-type>span img {
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    transform: translate(38px, -13px);
  }
  th:first-of-type {
    color: black;
  }
  th {
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
  }
  .date {
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  .date>span img {
    display: none;
  }
  th:first-of-type:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #838383;
    width: 2px;
    height: 15px;
    transform: translate(56px, -25px);
  }
  th:nth-of-type(2):after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #838383;
    width: 2px;
    height: 15px;
    transform: translate(15px, 3px);
  }
  th:nth-of-type(3)::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #838383;
    width: 1.5px;
    height: 15px;
    transform: translate(8px, 3px);
  }
  .email-table table tr:not(:nth-of-type(1)) {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    height: 95px;
  }
  .email-table table tr:not(:nth-of-type(1)):after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: black;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
  .email-table table tr:not(:nth-of-type(1)) td:first-of-type {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 1;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  .email-table table tr:not(:nth-of-type(1)):before {
    content: url('../assets/icon_mail_sp.svg');
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(15px, 10px);
  }
  .email-table table tr td:last-of-type {
    transform: translateX(120px);
  }
  .email-table table tr:not(:nth-of-type(4)) td:last-of-type::after {
    content: url('../assets/icon_arrow02.svg');
    width: 3px;
    height: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(3px);
  }
  .email-table table tr:nth-of-type(4) td:last-of-type span:last-of-type::after {
    content: url('../assets/icon_arrow02.svg');
    width: 3px;
    height: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(3px);
  }
  .second-data {
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 3;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: -1;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }
  .third-data {
    grid-row-start: 3;
    grid-row-end: 4;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: -1;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
  }
  td:last-of-type {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  .first-second-data {
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  .first-third-data {
    transform: translate(-20px, -27px);
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(2) td:first-of-type {
    transform: translate(20px, -2px);
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(2) td:nth-of-type(2) {
    transform: translate(20px, -15px);
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(2) td:nth-of-type(3) {
    transform: translate(5px, -15px);
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(3) td:first-of-type {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(3) td:first-of-type:after {
    visibility: visible;
    content: 'bbb.bbbb@example.com';
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-90px);
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(3) td:nth-of-type(2) {
    transform: translate(20px, -15px);
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(4) td:first-of-type {
    transform: translate(20px, -3px);
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(4) td:nth-of-type(2) {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(3) td:nth-of-type(2):after {
    visibility: visible;
    content: 'xxx@example.com, www.www@example.com';
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-108px, 92px);
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(5) td:first-of-type:after {
    visibility: visible;
    content: 'ddd.dddd@example.com';
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(-90px);
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(5) td:first-of-type {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .second-text span:first-of-type {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .second-text span:first-of-type:after {
    visibility: visible;
    content: 'vvv.vvv@example.com, uuu@example.com, ...';
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-150px, 15px);
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(6) td:first-of-type {
    transform: translate(20px);
  }
  .second-text span:last-of-type {
    transform: translate(40px, 15px);
    padding: 0 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
  .first-clip span:first-of-type img {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    transform: translateX(-5px);
  }
  .second-second-data {
    transform: translate(27px, -20px);
  }
  .second-third-data {
    transform: translate(10px, -10px);
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .third-second-data {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  .third-third-data {
    transform: translate(10px, -20px);
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .fourth-second-data {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  .fourth-third-data {
    transform: translate(7px, 2px);
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .fourth-third-data {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .fourth-third-data:after {
    visibility: visible;
    content: '[ HR-888 ] Notice of official announcement';
    position: absolute;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transform: translate(-160px, -40px);
  }
  .last-attachment span:first-of-type {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .last-attachment span:first-of-type:after {
    visibility: visible;
    content: 'sss@example.com, rrr.rrrr@example.com, ...';
    position: absolute;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transform: translate(-140px, 5px);
  }
  .last-attachment span:last-of-type {
    transform: translate(50px, 2px);
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 0 3px;
  }
  .fifth-second-data {
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  .fifth-third-data {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .fifth-third-data:after {
    visibility: visible;
    content: '[HR-887(Revised: Office Expansion Project Tea...';
    position: absolute;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transform: translate(-120px, -15px);
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  tr td:last-of-type>span img {
    transform: translateX(60px);
    display: block;
  }
  .first-clip span:last-of-type>span img {
    transform: translateX(3px);
    display: block;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(7) td {
    display: none;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(8) td {
    display: none;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(9) td {
    display: none;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(10) td,
  tr:nth-of-type(10) td:last-of-type {
    display: none;
  }
  tr:nth-of-type(11) td,
  tr:nth-of-type(11) td:last-of-type {
    display: none;
  }
  .email-table table tr:nth-of-type(6)~tr {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
HTML
<div class="email-table">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>From <span><img src="./assets/icon_arrow01.svg" alt=""></span></th>
      <th>To</th>
      <th>Subject</th>
      <th class="date">Date <span><img src="./assets/icon_arrow01.svg" alt=""></span></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>aaa@example.com</td>
      <td class="second-data first-second-data">zzz.zzz@example.com</td>
      <td class="third-data first-third-data">[ HR-888 ] Notice of official announcement</td>
      <td>0:20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bbb.bbbb@exam... </td>
      <td class="second-data second-second-data">yyy@example.com</td>
      <td class="third-data second-third-data">[web:333] "Web Contact"</td>
      <td>0:10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ccc@example.com </td>
      <td class="second-data third-second-data">
        <div class="text-attachment">
          <span>xxx@example.com, ...</span>
          <span>+1</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="third-data third-third-data">Happy New Year! Greetings for the New Year.</td>
      <td>
        <div class="attachment first-clip">
          <span><img src="./assets/icon_clip.svg" alt=""></span>
          <span>0:00</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ddd.dddd@exam...</td>
      <td class="second-data fourth-second-data">
        <div class="text-attachment second-text">
          <span>vvv.vvv@example.com, ... </span>
          <span>+1</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="third-data fourth-third-data">[HR-887(Revised: Office Expansion Project Team)] Notice of off... </td>
      <td>Jan 01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>eee@example.com</td>
      <td class="second-data fifth-second-data">
        <div class="text-attachment last-attachment">
          <span>sss@example.com, .... </span>
          <span>+2</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="third-data fifth-third-data">[Github] Logout page</td>
      <td>Jan 01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>fff.ffff@example.c... </td>
      <td>qqq.qqq@example.com</td>
      <td>［dev］ Postfix 3.1.12 / 3.2.9 / 3.3.4 / 3.4.5</td>
      <td>Jan 01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ggg@example.com </td>
      <td>ppp@example.com</td>
      <td>Re: [Github] Brush-up on loading animation </td>
      <td>Jan 01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>hhh.hhh@examp...</td>
      <td>ooo.ooo@example.com</td>
      <td>Workplace Summary for sample, Inc.: Jun 2 - Jun 9</td>
      <td>
        <div class="attachment">
          <span><img src="./assets/icon_clip.svg" alt=""></span>
          <span>Jan 01</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>iii@example.com</td>
      <td>nnn@example.com</td>
      <td>I love you</td>
      <td>
        <div class="attachment last-clip">
          <span><img src="./assets/icon_clip.svg" alt=""></span>
          <span>2019/12/31</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pablo-Diego-...</td>
      <td>Pablo-Diego-José-Francisc...
      </td>
      <td>[info:888] ABC EQUIPMENT COMPANY</td>
      <td>2019/12/31</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This works but there's a huge white space after the 6th element. Is there any way to get rid of that white space?

Comment: I see then you don't need to target the `::after` but the `tr` element itself. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the updated styles. It removes the lines but still that empty white space after the sixth element is visible.

Comment: It is if your window's height is greater than than of your content. Try resizing it! (you can't avoid a blank space if your content doesn't fill up the window)

Comment: Would that mean reducing the vh?

Comment: What I mean is that. See the video [here](https://bianco.tv/video/VPYIo). And use the full screen to actually see something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216593/discussion-between-tamarin-and-chinomso-johnson).